# Connect newly added Sheet to existing one

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post in Stack Overflow so any mistake I make please just ignore.

So i made an button which runs the macro of an application inputbox, the name you enter in the inputbox will create a new sheet with the name you entered, it also will create a table on the new sheet. The name you put on the inputbox are the clients that newly came so i will have specific sheet with table for every client that comes.

On the other hand I got the Workers which will receive incomes from clients, I Got 4 Workers which have their own Sheet and Table of Incomes and Outcomes.

Now the question i am getting to is that, is it possible to creade a code on VBA that will say: If on the new sheet (inside the table, specificly: K8:K23, K28:K43, K49:K64) the name of the Worker is inserted, copy the name of the client and paste it into the existing sheet of the Worker.

The code i tried but did not work: (Only Check the First Sub and the end of line, the between code is just a bunch of macro for table to be created, that parts work, the problem of my code which is located at the end is that it does nothing, and yes I did an commend to the codes on purpose)

```
    Sub KerkimiKlientit()
        Dim EmriKlientit As String
        Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
        Dim OutPut As Integer

    retry:

        EmriKlientit = Application.InputBox("Shkruani Emrin e Klientit", "Kerkimi")
        If Trim(EmriKlientit) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Hyrjet").Range("B10:B200")
                Set rng = .Find(What:=EmriKlientit, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    sheet:
                    Flag = 0
                    Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                        For i = 1 To Count
                            WS_Name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
                            If WS_Name = EmriKlientit Then Flag = 1
                        Next i
                            If Flag = 1 Then
                                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(EmriKlientit).Activate
                                Exit Sub
                            Else
                                Sheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = EmriKlientit
                                Call KrijimiTabeles(EmriKlientit)
                                Exit Sub
                            End If

                Else
                    OutPut = MsgBox("Klienti nuk u gjet", vbRetryCancel + vbInformation, "Provoni Perseri")
                        If (OutPut = vbRetry) Then
                            GoTo retry:
                        ElseIf (OutPut = vbCancel) Then
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End With
        End If
        If userInputValue = "" Then
            OutPut = MsgBox("Rubrika e Emrit e zbrazet", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation, "Gabim")
                If (OutPut = vbRetry) Then
                    GoTo retry:
                ElseIf (OutPut = vbCancel) Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        Else
            GoTo retry:
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub KrijimiTabeles(EmriKlientit As String)
    '
    ' KrijimiTabeles Macro
    '

    'This was just an middle code, it was too long so I did not paste it. Not an important part tho.







   'This is the part that does not work, it just does nothing for some reason, there are multiple codes here and I tried them all.

    'Sub Formula(EmriKlientit As String, ByVal Target As Range)
        'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(EmriKlientit).Activate
        'If Not Application.Intersect(Range("K8:K23"), Range(Target.Adress)) Is Nothing Then
        'Call Formula1
        'End If
    'End Sub
    'Dim LR As Long, i As Long
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        'Dim Rng As Range
        'For Each Rng In Range("K8:K23")
            'Select Case Rng.Value
                'Case "M"
                    'Worksheets(EmriKlientit).Range("K2").Copy
                    'Worksheets("Mustafa").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            'End Select
        'Next Rng
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'For Each cel In Rng
            'If cel.Value = "M" Then
                'Worksheets(EmriKlientit).Range("K2").Copy
                'Worksheets("Mustafa").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            'End If
        'Next cel


    'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(EmriKlientit).Activate
        'If Not Application.Intersect(Range("K8:K23"), Range(Rng.Adress)) Is Nothing Then
            'With Sheets(EmriKlientit)
                'With .Range("K8:K23")
                    'If .Text = "M" Then
                        'Worksheets(EmriKlientit).Range("K2").Copy
                        'Worksheets("Mustafa").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                    'End If
                'End With
            'End With
        'End If
        'Flag = 0
            'Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                'For i = 1 To Count
                    'WS_Name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
                    'If WS_Name = EmriKlientit Then Flag = 1
                        'Next i
                            'If Flag = 1 Then
                                'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(EmriKlientit).Activate
                                    'For Each Cell In Sheets(EmriKllientit).Range("K8:K23")
                                        'If Cell.Value = "M" Then
                                            'Range("K2").Copy
                                            'Worksheets("Mustafa").Range("K6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                                        'End If
                                    'Next
                            'End If

    End Sub
```

Thank you

I hope I was clear enough,
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your "question" is pretty broad and it's unclear what you are asking for (you didn't ask a question yet), probably have a look at [ask]. Also it is necessary that you show what you already tried to achieve your issue (show your relevant code part) and tell where *exactly* your difficulties are or where you got errors and which. Also screenshots can help a lot to illustrate a problem.

Comment: Okay, I will edit the post again, thank you for replying.  I will try to explain better.

Comment: I use a formula to get the number which is part of the sheet name to then drive vlookup() or index() with MATCH() to bring back data from a table - works fine. See : MID(CELL("filename",K1),FIND("W ",CELL("filename",K4))+2,2)*1 An example sheet name is "W 8 TD"

Comment: Solar Mike, can I combine that somehow on every newly sheet that Is added, so in vba macro I run?

Comment: @DespitePain *"did not work"* is a bad description for an error. We need to know what **exactly** does not work. Eg. is there an error message, if so where and which. Otherwise describe what your code actually does versus what you expected it should do. • Also your complete code is commented out every line is beginning with `'` which makes it a comment. Please clarify if this is only a typo/forrmat issue? Make sure the code is exactly the same that you have in your Editor. Every character matters.

Comment: I redited it, Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow - i agree that your question can be a bit more specific...

I think what you are trying to achieve is something between this lines:

```
Dim wsClient As Worksheet, wsMustafa As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long

Set wsClient = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Client")
Set wsMustafa= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mustafa")

'you can assign this through better ways, but to start with...
fRow = 8
lRow = 23

For i = fRow To lRow
    If wsClient.Range("K" & i).Value = "M" Then
        wsMustafa.Range("K6").Value = wsClient.Range("K" & i).Value 'or .Formula if that's what you want
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set, on line:
   If wsClient.Range("K" & i).Value = "M" Then

Comment: Hi.. forgot to declare the sheets... please amend the names as necessary.

Comment: Hello again, the client sheet is on the VBA macro code as a string,
I want the code to run automatically for every new client not only one sheet, because every client has it own Name and Sheet,
I tried:
`Set wsClient = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(EmriKlientit)` 'It means NameofClient and it is without quotes on purpose because it is a string.

Comment: From the code you posted as not working, I've seen a few different loops that you've tried, so I gave you a good (or so I hope) example on how you can use a loop to copy things from a range to another. Is up to you to implement that solution (or any other) within your existing code. I'll be happy to assist more, if you can share your full code related to this issue, ideally with a translation of the non-english words (to better understand what you are trying to achieve).